# Make constructor return specific instance type

Tags: typescript, class, constructor, instance

I'm writing TypeScript definitions file for a third-party library that exposes a global constructor function.

How do I write a class type which instance will be of a specific type?

```
declare class PexRTC {
  // this doesn't work, returned instance is PexRTC, not PexRTC.PexipInstance
  new(): PexRTC.PexipInstance;
}

declare namespace PexRTC {
    export interface PexipInstance {
        foo: true;
    }
}


// How to make instance be PexRTC.PexipInstance ?
const instance = new PexRTC();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBRTcSCwRh9akMQTCWhrR44ADCoAA3ooSpxIBIABQASnydGZbICTNWVAAkpxBKgzBYANyKAC%20wUpdL6nAYyEEBAYS0lLPZXJKJQh8DI6W232ShpQkplcoV5hQZvNnuS8HgItQZHYkBVnvV6oQLpEoAAvP0%20aLViahcEVDhmh4yF5EFbnMD2DQvm4zMx2AxmJB%20NT1IkGMC9CIvAAiACiq11C30DaS2Ib4AcqAA5MIAHJ8htBFQAeS%20ZHegnLWkgRwV1sgrmkeFATizOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuBYkVuiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCJSAA)

Comment: Please see the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html . I don't think it is correct to write `new()` inside `declare class`. However, I'm not very well familiar with writing `d.ts` files. See my solution https://tsplay.dev/NrGv0m

Comment: @captain-yossarian I tried this, but if you look at the .d.ts file in your link, the instance type is still `PexRTC`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok , so this is how to make it work:

```
declare const PexRTC: PexRTC.PexipInstance;

declare namespace PexRTC {
  export interface PexipInstance {
    new (): PexRTC.PexipInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: nice solution !